# Why is there extra paramaters in my simple CNN?

Tags: pytorch, conv-neural-network

Here is my problem : when I look for the number of parameters in my first block, I see 36928 parameters (which is what I expect). But when I used this block to construct a model in an other class `nn.Module`, there are 1792 extra parameters and I can't figure out where they come from.

I put some code below to illustrate.

```py
class Conv2dBlock(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_filters, out_filters, kernel_size=3):
        super(Conv2dBlock, self).__init__()
        self.conv2d_seq = torch.nn.Sequential()
        for k in range(2):
            self.conv2d_seq.append(torch.nn.Conv2d(in_channels=in_filters, out_channels=out_filters, kernel_size=kernel_size, padding='same'))
            self.conv2d_seq.append(torch.nn.ReLU())
            in_filters = out_filters
        
    def forward(self, input):
        out = self.conv2d_seq(input)
        return out
```

En then, I use this block in an other `nn.Module` :

```py
class EncoderBlock(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(EncoderBlock, self).__init__()
        self.conv2d = Conv2dBlock(3, 64)
        self.maxpool = torch.nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2)

    def forward(self, input):
        x = self.conv2d(input)
        p = self.maxpool(x)
        out = torch.nn.functional.dropout(p, 0.3)
        return x, out
```

And finaly :

```py
class UNet_model(torch.nn.Module): 
    def __init__(self):
        super(UNet_model, self).__init__()
        self.encoder_block1 = EncoderBlock()


    def forward(self, input):
        p1 = self.encoder_block1(input)
        # I removed useless code
        
        return p1


model = UNet_model()
summary(model, (3,128,128))
```

This last class constructs a model with 38 720 parameters, instead of 36 928. It seems there is an extra convolutional layer ((3,64, (3,3)) = 1792 params) applied twice to the input... I don't understand.

Can somebody take a look ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, `torch.nn.Sequential()` doesn't support `append` method, it should be changed to `add_module`, like this:

```
for k in range(2):
   self.conv2d_seq.add_module(f"conv_{k}",torch.nn.Conv2d(in_channels=in_filters, out_channels=out_filters, kernel_size=kernel_size, padding='same'))
   self.conv2d_seq.add_module(f"relu_{k}",torch.nn.ReLU())
   in_filters = out_filters
```

Second, if you run [torchinfo](https://github.com/tyleryep/torchinfo) `summary` on the initial block you will see:

```
==========================================================================================
Layer (type:depth-idx)                   Output Shape              Param #
==========================================================================================
Conv2dBlock                              [1, 64, 64, 64]           --
├─Sequential: 1-1                        [1, 64, 64, 64]           --
│    └─Conv2d: 2-1                       [1, 64, 64, 64]           1,792
│    └─ReLU: 2-2                         [1, 64, 64, 64]           --
│    └─Conv2d: 2-3                       [1, 64, 64, 64]           36,928
│    └─ReLU: 2-4                         [1, 64, 64, 64]           --
==========================================================================================
Total params: 38,720
Trainable params: 38,720
Non-trainable params: 0
Total mult-adds (M): 158.60
==========================================================================================
Input size (MB): 0.05
Forward/backward pass size (MB): 4.19
Params size (MB): 0.15
Estimated Total Size (MB): 4.40
==========================================================================================
```

So you can see that you have two conv layers  `(1,792 + 36,928)` as you specified 2 layers in your for loop: `for k in range(2)`.

Comment: Oh I see... What bugged me is that I thought the 36,928 was the *sum* of the layer parameters... And then when I use this block, summary adds up the two layers in one block and shows 38,720 parameters. Thanks for the clarification !